# .dat attachment instead of text using mailx in RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, email-attachments, mailx

I am trying to send the contents of a text file as the body of an attachment. This works fine in HP-UX, but we've recently moved to RedHat Linux, and it is no longer working as expected.

Here's my command

**cat test.txt | mailx -sTest me@email.ca**

If "test.txt" contains low ASCII characters, then it works fine. However, my text file may have French characters and will always contain a registered trademark symbol. It seems that when I try to send those characters, Linux is converting the email into an attachment (in the form attxxxxx.dat). The attachment has all my data, perfectly formed, but my recipients just want a plain email - not a "dat" attachment. We've tried setting the environment variables and putting extended character set commands in the mailx command, to no avail.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your file encoding is the same as the locale (man locale) set on your system. Either convert your file (e.g. using `iconv`) to the according locale or set the locale of the system to the current file encoding. Moreover make sure to remove any carriage returns from the file

`cat test_1.txt | tr -d '\r' > test_2.txt;`

Then `cat test_2.txt | mailx -s 'Test' me@email.ca;` should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use below small perl script before you send the file via mail command

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Toru's answer, I've been settled down to this command:

```
cat $FILE | tr -c -d '[:graph:][:blank:]\n\r\t' | mail -s "$FILE" somebody@example.com
```