# How to send mail with bash without attachment

Tags: bash, email

I'm trying to send a mail with a subject, a unique receiver, and few lines of text in the body. Almost everything is working as expected, except the body gets attached as a file instead of being in the mail's body.

Here is my code:

```
destinataire="foo@mail.com"
obj="** ALERTE BACKUP sur $host pour le dump DB de $db** "
body="Erreur lors du dump de la DB $db sur l'hote $host\n"
body="$body - Code erreur: $ret\n"
body="$body - Env: $prodfolder\n"
body="$body \n\nMail envoyé a $destinataire"
echo $body | mail -s "$obj" ${destinataire}
```

The content of `$body` gets transformed into a file, and attached to the mail. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, or if there is any additional configuration to do?

Comment: your example works fine with me...
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621899/dat-attachment-instead-of-text-using-mailx-in-redhat-linux as well

Comment: @xlembouras Cheers, it was due to french character in the body.

Comment: @renard Maybe put this in a separate answer and tick it off as "correct" for others who run into similar issues...

Comment: @Thomas i'm doing it :)

Comment: maybe provide the link above for completeness

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.dat attachment instead of text using mailx in RedHat Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621899/dat-attachment-instead-of-text-using-mailx-in-redhat-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to xlembouras, and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621899/dat-attachment-instead-of-text-using-mailx-in-redhat-linux), the problem as been solved:

Language-specific characters such as `é` combined with default encoding set to UTF-8 (on the system the mail is being sent from) leads the body of the message to be transferred as attachment instead of raw text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
mail -s "$obj" ${destinataire} <<EOF
Erreur lors du dump de la DB $db sur l'hote $host
 - Code erreur: $ret
 - Env: $prodfolder



Mail envoyé a $destinataire
EOF
```